# How to delete child objects when parent object delete mongodb nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to delete child objects where I am using parent object id as a reference, when I delete parent object in nodejs mongodb

Answer (score 2):

You need to query over all the relevant records and delete them.

Similarly, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362270/2059929).